# Why is this variable not being posted and giving an error?

Tags: php, mysql

Why is `bakeryid` variable not being posted in my form? The error I am receiving is

> "Notice:Undefined variable bakeryid"

I have two pages, one displays the form and the second is the action for the form. The second form kept saying that it was undefined also. The `bakeryid` is the ID for each cakes order.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `firstname`, `bakeryid`, `order` FROM cakes");

$bakeryid = $_POST['bakeryid'];

?>
  <table border='2'>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Order</th>
<?php
  echo '<form name="display" method="POST" action="cakephp.php">';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['order'] . "</td>";
    echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="bakeryid" value="' . $bakeryid . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="memid" value="' . $memid . '"/><input type="submit" name="takeorder" value="Take Order" ></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</form>";
  echo "</table>";
```

Answer:

```
echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="bakeryid" value="' . $row['bakeryid'] . '"/></td>';
```

Comment: Undefined variable what?

Comment: sorry the undefined variable is bakeryid

Comment: Where are you closing the `form`?

Comment: Please edit the question to state the exact error message (including what variable is undefined).  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @hjpotter92 good spot forgot to close the form

Comment: You have circular reasoning here.  You set `$bakeryid` with `$_POST['bakeryid']`, but then define bakeryid with `$bakeryid`.  There is never any input from the user, or from the program.  You should set it with `$row['bakeryid']` like the others.

Comment: how could i do that without it being displayed in the form, i don't want the bakeryid displayed in the form @SableFoste

Comment: Note, it is still hidden; please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `$bakeryid` with `$_POST['bakeryid']`, but then define bakeryid with `$bakeryid`.

Please try:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `firstname`, `bakeryid`, `order` FROM cakes c INNER JOIN members m ON c.memid = m.memid");

$bakeryid = $_POST['bakeryid']; // this line is unnecessary

    ?> <table border='2'>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Order</th>
<?php
        echo '<form name="display" method="POST" action="cakephp.php">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
            {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['order'] . "</td>";
                    echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="bakeryid" value="' . $row['bakeryid'] . '"/></td>'; // this line changed
                    echo  '<td><input type="hidden" name="memid" value="' . $memid . '"/><input type="submit" name="takeorder" value="Take Order" ></td>';
                echo "</tr>";
            }
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: i see what you mean now thanks for the help *thumbs up* it's working now

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `firstname`, `bakeryid`, `order` FROM cakes c INNER JOIN members m ON c.memid = m.memid");

$bakeryid = $_POST['bakeryid']; ?> 
<table border='2'>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Order</th>
<?php
        echo '<form name="display" method="POST" action="cakephp.php">';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
                echo '<tr>
                          <td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>
                          <td>' . $row['order'] . '</td>
                          <td><input type="hidden" name="bakeryid" value="' . $row['bakeryid'] . '"/></td>
                          <td><input type="hidden" name="memid" value="' . $memid . '"/>
                              <input type="submit" name="takeorder" value="Take Order" >
                          </td>
                     </tr>';
        }
echo '</form></table>';
```

The reason bakeryid isn't appearing in the form, is when setting the fields value you are using $bakeryid which is set to a post that hasn't happened yet. You want to set the value to $row['bakeryid'] as above.